# Rust function that takes an iterator, and returns an iterator with mutated items?

Tags: rust, iterator, mutable

I want to write a function that takes one iterator as input, and return an iterator with the same items but mutated. Like in this example:

```
fn greet(name: &mut String) {
    name.insert_str(0, "Hello ");
}

fn to_greetings(names: impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
    names.inspect(|name| greet(name))
}
```

This does not compile, since `name` isn't mutable. I have tried adding `mut` in various places without really understanding what I am doing, but without any success. How do I fix the above code?

I guess I need to make the items mutable, but apparently `Item = mut String` is a syntax error.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me how you want to use this iterator. Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the item type of an iterator is `String`, the iterator yields *owned* strings. The iterator transfers ownership of these strings to the consumer. The consumer can modify the strings, since it owns them.

However, you can't use `inspect()` to modify the elements of an iterator. The closure passed to `inspect()` receives an immutable reference to the items of the iterator, which can't be used to modify the items. The correct iterator adapter to modify items is `map()`, so this works (but it doesn't feel particularly idiomatic to me):

```
fn to_greetings<I>(names: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = String>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = String>,
{
    names.map(|mut name| { greet(&mut name); name })
}
```

If you want to actually modify the strings in some underlying container, e.g. a vector of strings, you need a different approach though. A mutable iterator over a container of strings has an item type of `&mut String`, so you'd need to use something like

```
fn to_greetings<'a, I>(names: I) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a mut String>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a mut String>,
{
    names.map(|name| { greet(name); name })
}
```